# An issue with the usual proof of Cantor's Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

It seems to me that the standard proof of Cantor's Theorem also "proves" that $\left|\mathcal{P}(X)\right| < \left|\mathcal{P}(X)\right|$.

[The following is adopted from Hrbacek & Jech.]

> Let $f$ be a mapping of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ into $\mathcal{P}(X)$. Consider the set $S = \{y \in \mathcal{P}(X) \mid y \notin f(y)\}$. We claim that $S$ is not in the range of $f$. Suppose that $S = f(z)$ for some $z \in \mathcal{P}(X)$. By definition of $S$, $z \in S$ if and only if $z \notin f(z)$. But we assumed $S = f(z)$, so we get $z \in S$ if and only if $z \notin S$, a contradiction. This shows that $f$ is not onto $\mathcal{P}(X)$ and the proof of $\left|\mathcal{P}(X)\right| < \left|\mathcal{P}(X)\right|$ is complete.

I can't see a good reason why the above is any more wrong than the proof of $\left|X\right| < \left|\mathcal{P}(X)\right|$. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your set $S$ is a *subset* of $\mathcal{P} (X)$, *i.e.*, it is an element of $\mathcal{P} ( \mathcal{P} ( X ) )$.  So it will not (in general) be a possible output of  $f$.  (Also, your definition of $S$ has a similar problem: it is as though you are asking if a subset $y$ of $X$ is an element of $f(y)$, which is itself a subset of $X$.  Basically, you're mixing up the types of objects you are considering.)

Comment: To be specific, what you're trying to do is find an element of $P(X)$ not in the range of $f$, but you have failed to do so, finding instead an element of $P(P(X))$ not in the range of $f$.

Comment: I see. Is there a specific sentence in the proof where it first "goes off the tracks", so to speak? It's definitely wrong, but the statement "Suppose that $S = f(z)$..." is made in the context of a proof by contradiction, so how would it be wrong in the context of formal logic / a computerized proof verifier?

Comment: @JackM Still synthesizing your comment in my head, but I think it may answer the question I just asked.

Comment: Okay, yep I get it now. The key statement is "We claim that $S$ is not in the range of $f$", which proves nothing since $S \notin \mathcal{P}(X)$.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: Sorry. Was away for a bit. Yes, after assuming (for the sake of contradiction) that $S$ is in the range of $f$, then you take some $z \subseteq X$ such that $f(z) = S$.  But this (in general) will never be possible because $S$ is a _subset_ of $\mathcal{P} (X)$, and so will not be itself an _element_ of $\mathcal{P}(X)$.  So, of course $S$ is not in the range of $f$: it couldn't be.  Just like $\mathcal{P} ( \mathcal{P} ( \mathcal{P} (X) ) )$ is also not in the range of $f$.